# Particle.js library error on pages where it's html selectors is not used

Tags: javascript, wordpress, particles.js

I am using Particle.js  library to use particles as background, here is the github link https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js
I am using this on my WordPress site. After including library I used particles background on one pages, it works fine , but creates problem on those pages where it's html selector is not present(where particle-js id is not present).
this is js error appears on those pages where this is not present:

> TypeError: pJS_tag is null particles.js?ver=1.0 line 1495

Here is my HTML code:`<div id="particles-js"></div>`

This is my js code:

```
if($('#particles-js').length > 0){
        particlesJS("particles-js", {"particles":{"number":{"value":80,"density":{"enable":true,"value_area":800}},"color":{"value":"#d5d5d4"},"shape":{"type":"circle","stroke":{"width":0,"color":"#c7cbd2"},"polygon":{"nb_sides":5},"image":{"src":"img/github.svg","width":100,"height":100}},"opacity":{"value":0.5,"random":false,"anim":{"enable":false,"speed":1,"opacity_min":0.1,"sync":false}},"size":{"value":8.33451405615796,"random":true,"anim":{"enable":false,"speed":40,"size_min":0.1,"sync":false}},"line_linked":{"enable":true,"distance":150.02125301084325,"color":"#d5d5d5","opacity":1,"width":1.1668319678621144},"move":{"enable":true,"speed":6,"direction":"none","random":false,"straight":false,"out_mode":"out","bounce":false,"attract":{"enable":false,"rotateX":600,"rotateY":1200}}},"interactivity":{"detect_on":"canvas","events":{"onhover":{"enable":true,"mode":"repulse"},"onclick":{"enable":true,"mode":"push"},"resize":true},"modes":{"grab":{"distance":400,"line_linked":{"opacity":1}},"bubble":{"distance":400,"size":40,"duration":2,"opacity":8,"speed":3},"repulse":{"distance":200,"duration":0.4},"push":{"particles_nb":4},"remove":{"particles_nb":2}}},"retina_detect":true});
        //var count_particles, stats, update; stats = new Stats; stats.setMode(0); 
        var stats, update; stats = new Stats; stats.setMode(0); 
        stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute'; 
        stats.domElement.style.left = '0px'; 
        stats.domElement.style.top = '0px'; 
        document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement); 
        //count_particles = document.querySelector('.js-count-particles'); 
        update = function() {
            stats.begin(); 
            stats.end(); 
            // if (window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles && window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array) {
            //      count_particles.innerText = window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.length; 
            // } 
            requestAnimationFrame(update); 
        }; //requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the library file before closing `head` tag in `header.php` file

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/demowp/wp-content/themes/sydney/js/particles.js?ver=2.1.4'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/demowp/wp-content/themes/sydney/js/stats.js?ver=2.1.4'></script>
</head>
```

and include div anywhere wherever you want.

```
<div id="particles-js"></div>
```

Add this script in `footer.php` file

```
<script>
    if(jQuery('#particles-js').length){
        particlesJS("particles-js", {"particles":{"number":{"value":80,"density":{"enable":true,"value_area":800}},"color":{"value":"#d5d5d4"},"shape":{"type":"circle","stroke":{"width":0,"color":"#c7cbd2"},"polygon":{"nb_sides":5},"image":{"src":"img/github.svg","width":100,"height":100}},"opacity":{"value":0.5,"random":false,"anim":{"enable":false,"speed":1,"opacity_min":0.1,"sync":false}},"size":{"value":8.33451405615796,"random":true,"anim":{"enable":false,"speed":40,"size_min":0.1,"sync":false}},"line_linked":{"enable":true,"distance":150.02125301084325,"color":"#d5d5d5","opacity":1,"width":1.1668319678621144},"move":{"enable":true,"speed":6,"direction":"none","random":false,"straight":false,"out_mode":"out","bounce":false,"attract":{"enable":false,"rotateX":600,"rotateY":1200}}},"interactivity":{"detect_on":"canvas","events":{"onhover":{"enable":true,"mode":"repulse"},"onclick":{"enable":true,"mode":"push"},"resize":true},"modes":{"grab":{"distance":400,"line_linked":{"opacity":1}},"bubble":{"distance":400,"size":40,"duration":2,"opacity":8,"speed":3},"repulse":{"distance":200,"duration":0.4},"push":{"particles_nb":4},"remove":{"particles_nb":2}}},"retina_detect":true});
        //var count_particles, stats, update; stats = new Stats; stats.setMode(0); 
        var stats, update; stats = new Stats; stats.setMode(0); 
        stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute'; 
        stats.domElement.style.left = '0px'; 
        stats.domElement.style.top = '0px'; 
        document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement); 
        //count_particles = document.querySelector('.js-count-particles'); 
        update = function() {
            stats.begin(); 
            stats.end(); 
            // if (window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles && window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array) {
            //      count_particles.innerText = window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.length; 
            // } 
            requestAnimationFrame(update); 
        }; //requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }

</script>
```

Its working fine. [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/ot1bv7xw/3/)

Comment: "TypeError: pJS_tag is null"  and it's coming from particle.js file which I downloaded from github.

Comment: Did you include stats.js?

Comment: Yes , I included stats.js

Comment: can you explain how you include `particles.js` in your theme and where you use above the script? separate js file or footer.php file?

Comment: I am including them before closing body tag, and used separate js files for them.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Yes it's working in fiddle but again showing same error when I am using with WordPress site.

Comment: If I am using with static id then it works, but  it's not working with dynamic id, beacuse every time dynamic id is generated and I am sending this using data attribute.